# Let buffered image but not the panel disappear for 3 seconds

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, paint

I created a `JPanel` with a blue background and then I add a buffered image to it.

Now the image, but not the whole panel, should disappear for 3 seconds, when the user clicks on the image (only the image not the panel!)

Would someone be so kind to point me to the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyPanelTest extends JPanel{
    
    public BufferedImage image;

    public int xDelta, yDelta;
    public int xPos, yPos;

    
    public MyPanelTest() {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        xPos = 150;
        yPos = 180;
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/siegel.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, xPos, yPos, 150, 150, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be easier if using a `JLabel` to display the image. Is there a reason it is custom painted?

Comment: **General Tips** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Choose tags carefully. Without the well known [tag:java] and [tag:swing] tags, this question has got around 1 view per 3 days. 3) Don't load resources in a paint method! Load the image when the class is being constructed and keep a reference to it.